# Magento 2 Cannot override vendor file

Tags: adminhtml, overrides

Here am trying to override a admin page, but it cannot override, 
here is admin path:

```
/public_html/vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/frontend/templates/tracking/details.phtml
```

Override path :

```
/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/Magento/Magento_Shipping/adminhtml/templates/tracking/details.phtml
```

OR

```
/public_html/app/design/adminhtml/Magento/Magento_Shipping/templates/tracking/details.phtml
```

Where am doing wrong, Can I get help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: as you are trying to override `adminhtml` template either you need to create adminhtml theme Or override using custom module

Comment: @Pawan, thank you for response, am overriding  `adminhtml` template am created new folder `Magento_Shipping` and added path. not created new theme

Comment: for apply custom admin theme you also need to create module so you can override it by module without creating admin theme..

Comment: @Pawan Thank you, I will do it